# sending data from android to mysql database

Tags: java, php, android, web-services

Hi Im trying to send data from android device to mysql database. Im phone and laptop are connected to the internet via wifi. My phone is connected to the laptop via usb cable. I'm not using the emulator. In my java code I've tried using my 10.0.0.2 and 127.0.0.1 and neither one worked. I've done some reading on stackoverflow and its to my understanding that those to only work on emulator. When I input some data into the app and click the send button it says that the data was entered successfully and no errors in the logcat but when I check the database there is no entries. I think im using the wrong address or my linker.php file is located in the wrong place. I then tried using my IP ADDRESS. In my java code for the main activity i have.

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://'IP ADDRESS'/linker.php");
```

I've changed the Apache http.config so now it has the line

```
Listen 'IP ADDRESS'
```

I have the internet permissions in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Here is my linker.php which is located inside of my htDocs folder

```
<?php 

$con=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con); //The name of the database

$name=$_POST['name'];
$age=$_POST['age'];

mysql_query("insert into mytable(name, age) values('($name)', '($age)')");
?>
```

Here is what I see when I open the linker.php file in browser. I should have checked this before. How do I fix this.

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\linker.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\linker.php on line 7
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested the php code separately? Maybe your db connection info is incorrect.

Comment: is the db password empty '' or a single space as you have it now ' ' ?

Comment: @BarbiePylon I just tried opening the php file and I noticed some errors. Please see updated question. Also when im on mysql database the server is 127.0.0.1. Im not sure if this is the problem but if it is how do i chnage it to my IP address?

Comment: @dbinns66 its supposed to be empty

Comment: make sure you set $con = mysql_connect...

Comment: Change $con-mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') to $con=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

Comment: @BarbiePylon Ive made the changes thanks. i stil get errors on line 5 and 6 though

Comment: You get those errors because you're not making a POST request so those variables aren't there. To truly test this you'll have to actually make a POST request, but it looks like you're connection problems have been solved. Try through your app again!

Comment: @BarbiePylon thanks but at the moment the database still isnt receiving any data from app. my ip address is 5.67......... but localhost is 127.0.0.1 on mysql database, could this be the problem.

Comment: You're running this all locally, correct? Have you tested connectivity to your web server from your phone? Try hitting some random page (create a sample HTML page) from your phone's browser. Maybe your apache config is incorrect or your router is blocking incoming connections on port 80.

Comment: @BarbiePylon i just tried looking up my laptop ipv4 address on my phone and it says 'Access forbidden'. and access is only available from localhost. it also says settings can be configurated in file "http-xampp-conf". not sure what configurations are needed but and ask another question and ill look it up. thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmmm. Yeah, I would try to make sure the connectivity from your phone to your laptop works first and then continue with hitting the PHP service.

Answer (score 0):

OK, well, it looks like $_POST does not contain 'name' and 'age', I'd do a print_r($_POST) in as the first executable statement just to see what $_POST contains...

Secondly, the query is a little off... try

```
mysql_query("insert into mytable(name, age) values('$name', '$age')");
```

Comment: hi thanks but t the moment the database still isnt receiving any data from app. my ip address is 5.67......... but localhost is 127.0.0.1 could thiss be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the way data is being posted to the webservice linker.php has the issue. Check that process, as the undefined index will only appear if $_POST is empty.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi thanks for your help. i think that the java code that indicates where my linker.php file is might be wrong, since the file is located in the localhost folder whereas my java code says IP address/linker.php. but i dont know how to fix this since i cant use localhost/linker.php.